# s3 intelligent tiering, getting storage-class invalid choice at CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

#### Update - how to upgrade aws cli? my attempts failed.

I get the following.
I've tried different regions and intelligent tiering works ok in the management console UI.  But using the CLI I get:

```
$ aws s3 cp aws_aliases.sh --storage-class INTELLIGENT_TIERING s3://snap2web1
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --storage-class: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

STANDARD                                 | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY                      
STANDARD_IA
```

I tried updating my aws cli but that didn't help:

```
$ aws --version                                                                                                                                                           
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-65-generic botocore/1.8.48   

$ pip install --upgrade awscli                                                                                                                                            
Collecting awscli
...  

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.14.44 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-65-generic botocore/1.8.48
```

I tried upgrading my aws version from 1.44 to 1.61 but

```
    $ pip install --upgrade awscli
```

didn't do it.

I then removed awscli and reinstalled it but I still get 1.44

How to upgrade ?

Update: After update (`sudo snap install aws-cli --classic`):

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.148 Python/3.6.7 Linux/4.15.0-65-generic botocore/1.12.138
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using an outdated version of the cli, please upgrade.  What version are you using?

```
aws --version
```

Support for intelligent tier was added in version 1.16.61 of the aws cli as can be seen in the [Github project](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/commit/71f970fd26656190916423a6e3fd91ed3d33433c#diff-46607fbd76883995d41046735ccc8ac1).

Comment: Good idea.  1.14.44  I tried upgrading (added to question) but it didn't help

Comment: The latest version is like 1.16.255, upgrade to that and try again.  For example, support for ONEZONE_IA storage class was added in 1.15.9 version.

Comment: How are you installing it, you can also try and install it via pip:  pip install awscli

Comment: i just did that and same result 1.44

Comment: You mentioned you removed it first, how did you do that?  I'm wondering if awscli is installed via your system package manager and not via pip.  One thing you can try, if you haven't tried already is to uninstall it via your system package management tool, then try the pip install again.  So something like apt-get remove awscli if you are using debian/ubuntu

Comment: I did that and it removed one but didn't help.  The I did `sudo snap install aws-cli --classic` and it fixed it if you want to add that please

Comment: The `awscli` and `aws-cli` thing is a bit subtle too. I might have missed that initially. ` aws-cli` is the variant that worked

Comment: I'm glad you resolved the issue but you probably shouldn't have updated your question to include your upgrade attempts because that changes the nature of the original question you were asking on why it appeared the CLI didn't support the latest storage options, which was answered correctly that you needed to upgrade your aws CLI version.  How to upgrade should probably have been a separate question.  I'd recommend removing the updates to your question to include the upgrade information and accept the answer as is.  It'll be more useful for posterity.

Comment: I was planning to do that after u added more detail about it and I also will accept your answer. Ty

Comment: Not sure what more detail I should add.  How one updates the awscli depends on your platform.  I've added an explicit statement in my response to upgrade using whatever tool is suitable for your platform.